# Select all sql records within hour range

Tags: sql, date, time

I have a sql table called morecrimes. I would like to select every record that occurred after 10pm and before 6am regardless of date.

I know I should use datepart but cannot quite get it to fire

There is a column is called date and has values like '2013-09-13 16:45:59'

Is the below SQL on the right track?

```
SELECT datepart('hour',date)>22
from morecrimes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM morecrimes
WHERE datepart('hour',date)>=22
OR datepart('hour',date)<6
```